# How to remove/hide personal directories on desktop screen?

Tags: 22.04, files, directory, home-directory

How do I remove/hide my personal directories (`Music`, `Documents`, etc) from the desktop?

After an update, my desktop changed and is showing my personal directories (`Music`, `Documents`, etc). Before the update, the `Home` directory was the only directory on the desktop. I can hide the `Home` directory, that does work, but hiding the `Home` directory does not hide my personal directories (`Music`, `Documents`, etc).

The personal directories (`Music`, `Documents`, etc) on the desktop are the same folders in my `Home` directory.

Showing the desktop folders and properties:

[image: desktop folders and properties]

Showing `Home` folder and properties:

[image: 'Home' folder and properties]

Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: I believe the control of desktop icons is achieved using the Gnome Extension `Desktop Icons NG (DING). Have you got that extension installed?

Answer (score 1):

Fix it as following.

1. Open the terminal
2. Reset your "special folders" configuration with the command:

   ```
   xdg-user-dirs-update --force
   ```

This recreates the configuration file that identifies your "special folders". It may eventually recreate special folders if these would not anymore exist.

The configuration of special folders may break when you delete/move/rename a special folder with other tools than a graphical file manager.